Oracle listener does not accept shared server connections after switchover
I have Oracle 11g DB with primary and standby server. My primary server was configured to accept shared servers connections.
I had made a switchover, shutdown the old primary and changed the new primary IP to be the same as old primary.
However, after reconfiguring the listener, it stopped accepting shared servers connection reporting the following error:
ORA-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found

So the listener file is exactly the same (except DB global name), DB parameters are the same but shared servers do not work.
What am I doing wrong?
LISTENER.ORA
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORADB_STDBY)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\db_1)
      (SID_NAME = ORADB)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\db_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.22.123.54)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\oracle

DB parameters:
processes                            integer     900
max_shared_servers                   integer     150
shared_server_sessions               integer
shared_servers                       integer     50
dispatchers                          string      (protocol=TCP)(disp=8)(con=600
                                                 )(sess=5000)
max_dispatchers                      integer     5

